# what mean string in {}?

Tags: php

I have string

```
$name = 'user';

$run->{$name};
```

And i have result notice :

```
Undefined property: run::$user
```

I have in controller method user, but in error i see string ang $ char.

Is this is a some special char ?

Answer (score 3):

`obj->{$foo}` is equivalent to `obj->bar` if the string in `$foo` is `'bar'`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php for more details.

If `obj->bar` is actually a *method*, you should be calling it as `obj->bar()`...

And thus `object->{$foo}()` - note the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

`$run->{$name}` is like you  have written `$run->user` , this is used when you want to access property of object using value of variable

so if `$name = 'user';`

then `$run->{$name}` will try to get property with the name 'user'

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "user";
$run->{$name}();
```

to run a method user();

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method in the controller (an instance of which you've captured in `$run`) you can use:

```
$run->$name();
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) The braces are required when only part of the string is the variable name and PHP would interpret it incorrectly. In all other cases they are optional and are placed for better readability (the same way as () braces are used in expressions). Since you are referring to method, and not a property, you have to use (). It's the same even when you don't use variable variables:

```
$foo->user // access to property
$foo->user() // method call
```